# Multiple azure users managing the same VM

Tags: azure

Is it possible to have two or more users managing the same VM that one of them created on Azure?

For example:

My colleague created a VM.

Everyday the first one of us who arrive at work would like to turn it on. We don't want to wait to the VM creator to arrive.

The same problem happens by the end of the day. Since the last one of us at the office will turn it off and she might need to stay longer or connect from home to turn it off if I need to finish some work at the VM.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, Azure has got a [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure) for permissions role assignment.
As for your particular case, you would need to assign contributor permissions to resource group or to a VM, or use one of the pre-build roles, say VM Contributor, to restrict access.

Also, if you have contributor access at subscription level, you should have access to shutting down a VM.

Comment: Thank you! I will check right now!